# When I use Mockito from their latest 2.0.3 Beta jar I get a class not found exception for org.objenesis.ObjenesisStd class

Tags: junit, mockito

I have a normal web based servlet running on Tomcat that  I am trying to test.

I just cloned Mockito from their github repo and built it and got the mockito-core-2.0.3-beta.jar.

I added this jar to my project and when I use it as below

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DailyEmailSenderTest {

private ArrayList<MailVO> mails;

@Mock
private SqlDatabaseAccess db;
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {

}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
}

@Test
public void testGetMailsListFromDB() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}
}
```

I get a class not found exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objenesis/ObjenesisStd
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objenesis.ObjenesisStd
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more than the mockito-core jar.  If you look at the pom in maven central, it shows dependencies on both hamcrest-core 1.1 and this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
  <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Should be good if you also add those jars to your classpath.